# How to estimate this analytic function from Stein's Complex Analysis Chap2 Problem2

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $F(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}d(n)z^n$, for $\vert z\vert <1$.
It's easy to verify that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}d(n)z^n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{1-z^n}$,
however , I really have no idea how to obtain the following estimation which concludes that for $\theta=2\pi p/q$ , we have $\vert F(re^{i\theta})\vert\geq c_{p/q}\frac{1}{1-r}\log(1/(1-r))$.

Thanks.

Comment: is d(n) the divisor function?

Comment: oops，yes , d(n) is the divisor function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume $(p,q)=1$ and note that for $n$ not a multiple of $q$, one has $2\pi-2\pi/q \ge \arg n\theta \ge 2\pi/q$ so $|1-z^n| \ge a_{p,q}>0$ hence $|\sum_{n=1, n \ne rq}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{1-z^n}| \le \frac{1}{a_{p,q}}\sum_{n=1, n \ne mq}r^n \le b_{p,q}$

On the other hand for $n=mq$ one has $\frac{z^n}{1-z^n}=\frac{r^{mq}}{1-r^{mq}}$ and $1-r^{mq}=(1-r)(1+r+..+r^{mq-1}) \le mq(1-r)$ so $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{mq}}{1-z^{mq}}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{r^{mq}}{1-r^{mq}} \ge \frac{1}{1-r}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{r^{mq}}{mq}=\frac{1}{1-r}\log \frac{1}{1-r^{q}}$$

Now $$\log \frac{1}{1-r^{q}}=\log \frac{1}{1-r}-\log (1+r+..+r^{q-1}) \ge \log \frac{1}{1-r}-\log q$$

So putting all together we get for $z=re^{i\theta}, \theta=2\pi p/q, (p,q)=1$:

$$|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{1-z^n}| \ge \frac{1}{1-r}\log \frac{1}{1-r}-\frac{1}{1-r}\log q -b_{p,q}$$ and since $\log \frac{1}{1-r} \to \infty, r\to 1$, the required result follows for $r \ge \epsilon >0$ while for $r$ small the result is trivial as both sides are ~ $r$